# Swagger with Spring Boot and AWS Lambda

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am trying to deploy a spring boot , Java, Swagger application, everything is working fine except the swagger UI.

I am getting this below error.

```
File path not allowed: /swagger-ui.html

at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.SecurityUtils.getValidFilePath
(SecurityUtils.java:192) ~[task/:na]
```

Comment: Are you able to resolve the issue

Comment: Are you trying to use spring-fox swagger ? What version of spring boot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old bug in Amazon's library.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-spring</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Use the latest (or higher than 1.2).

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/pull/205

Comment: My java container spring version is 1.3.1

Comment: Do you have your pom on github ?

Comment: or the full project per se ?

Answer (score 0):

Its a configuration issue. You need to check the configuration part. I have mentioned few tutorials,have a look int it.

- [Configure Swagger With Jersey and Spring Boot](https://frugalisminds.com/spring-boot/configure-swagger-with-jersey-and-spring-boot/)
- [Spring Boot + Swagger2](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot_swagger)
- [How to add Swagger to Spring Boot -Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gduKpLW_vdY)
- [How to configure Swagger in Spring Boot -Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8s9I1G4tXhA)

Comment: Why does the mentioned error come? If I receive this error, what configuration change should I do to fix that?